# Create a CSV file in the local system dynamically

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am trying to create a CSV file dynamically in the user's system whoever uses my Application so that I can write data into it and then import it to an Excel.

Once I am done with my Application, I am deploying the WAR file in the Tomcat Server in the Server system. I am trying to use System.getProperty("user.home") for creating the file in a particular path. But the file is creating in the system where the App is deployed (Server system).

Different users will be using the App in different systems,so how can I get the path for creating a file in the Local Host System (user's system)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat knows nothing about the user who is opening the web page. Tomcat is using `user.home` of those user who started the tomcat instance. You should create custom login permissions with session and map your website accounts to local system users.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have no idea of how to create custom login permission with session? Can you please help me out?

Comment: You should first understand sessions. Please, read this howto
http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/tomcat/persistent-sessions

Comment: Thanks for the link. So after creating the session, how can I map my website to local systems?

Comment: This require custom coding. You should somehow define your web-users then try to locate system user who has the same login name as your web-user. Then knowing his password you could execute shell command to get his home directory.